# Program doesn't seem to enter while

Tags: java, logic

I am trying to make a program that inputs coin values in order to give tickets, but it doesn't seem to get into the first while and when i run it first of all it doesn't accept doubles(ex. 0.1 or 0.5) and no matter what number you enter it says Here is your ticket and ends! what is wrong with the code?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class tickets extends ConsoleProgram {
    public static double eisitirio = 1.2;
    public void run(){
    double nomisma=readInt("Insert coins and then press 0: ");
    boolean synthiki=false;
    double poso=0;
    while (synthiki=false){
        while (nomisma != 0){
            if ((nomisma==0.1)||(nomisma==0.2)||(nomisma==0.5)||(nomisma==1)||(nomisma==2)||(nomisma==5)){
            poso=poso+nomisma;
            }else {
                System.out.println("You did not insert a supported coin, please insert another one");
            }
            nomisma=readInt("Insert coins and then press 0: ");
        }
        if (poso < eisitirio){
            System.out.println("You did not insert enough money, please insert more coins");
        }else {
            synthiki=true;
        }
    }
    println("Here is your ticket");
    poso=poso-eisitirio;
    if ((poso/5) > 0){
        println("You have change: 5 euros");
        poso = poso-5;
    }
    if ((poso/2) > 0){
        println("You have change: 2 euros");
        poso = poso-2;
    }
    if ((poso/1) > 0){
        println("You have change: 1 euros");
        poso = poso-1;
    }   
    if ((poso/0.5) > 0){
        println("You have change: 50 cents");
        poso = poso-0.5;
    }
    if ((poso/0.2) > 0){
        println("You have change: 20 cents");
        poso = poso-0.2;
    }
    if ((poso/0.1) > 0){
        println("You have change: 10 cents");
        poso=poso-0.1;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using '==' instead of '='. One equals means assign, two equals mean check for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "==" for **comparison**, not "=" (**assignment**). Change

```
while (synthiki=false)
```

to

```
while (synthiki == false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You condition,

```
while (synthiki=false){...}
```

should be,

```
while (!synthiki){...}
```

The first condition assigns `false` to `synthiki`. Since, `synthiki` is a `boolean`, you can use the variable directly inside the `while() {...}`. Also if you had to check the value of `synthiki`, use `==` instead of `=`.

Like: `while(synthiki == false) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator. It assigns the right hand side expression's value to the left hand side variable, and returns it. If you want to check for equality, you should use the `==` operator:

```
while (synthiki == false) {
```

Or better yet, since it's a boolean variable, don't compare its value to a literal, but evaluate it directly:

```
while (!synthiki) {
```